# Calculate starting time and duration of a digital signal in python

Tags: python, datetime, time, timestamp, string-formatting

I am having a hard "time" trying to use `time` and `datetime` in Python to achive a fairly simple goal. I have already worked with those modules, and have read documentation, but I think I am not getting it the right way.

I have a digital signal (a long array) which represents a time series recorded with a given sampling rate, say, N samples per second.

I have a list of tuples in the following format (dummy data):

```
[(150, 150),
 (450, 90),
 (750, 150),
 (1050, 90),
 (1350, 150),
 (1650, 90),
 ...
 (1950, 150)]
```

Each tuple represents starting sample and number of samples of a given interval. Intervals are consecutive, so starting sample is monotonically increasing.

What I want is to get strings representing starting time and duration the interval (since each sample has a fixed known duration, determined by sampling rate), like this:

```
[('00:12.000', '2.245'),
 ('00:15.057', '2.158'),
 ('00:18.857', '3.045'),
 etc.]
```

(IMPORTANT: these values are not intended for calculation, just to give an idea of structure and formatting. The values are arbitrarily typed numbers)

I can imagine very ugly ways to get this with rounding and subtraction and modulo division and the like, but I think Python, with all those beautiful time manipulation modules, MUST have a pythonic way to get what I need.

Anyone?

Thanks for reading!
(and hope the coming answers might enlighten the path of other people in the future)

Comment: Do you know that in the second example that's a list of strings and not a list of tuples, don't you? The parenthesis are useless there.

Comment: What have you already tried?  Also, I'm having a hard time understanding how we are supposed to calculate the relationship between the first set of tuples you listed and the second set of values you listed.

Comment: From the first rows of your two lists, it appears that 150 samples take 2.245 seconds, meaning your sample rate is 0.015 seconds. But in the second row, 90 samples take 2.158 seconds, meaning the sample rate is 0.024 seconds. Maybe the example needs to be fixed?

Comment: @MikePennington : the actual values are meaningless, because I just typed random data. Only the formatting is important. Also, lists or tuples for me would work the same. I want start times in MM:SS.SSS format, and intervals in SS.SSS format, without leading zeros.

Comment: @mtrw : I considered fixing the example, but that would give too much work because I don't have the code to do it :o) . Anyway, my sampling period is around 0.01 or 0.001 seconds, that's not critical.

Comment: @rubik: now I see it! Thanks, I'll fix!

Comment: If you just want the duration in seconds (without converting to minutes for cuts longer than 60), then you don't need either "rounding, subtraction, or modulo division" or "time manipulation modules".  Just format it with `"%.3f"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import timedelta

il = [(150, 150),
      (450, 90),
      (750, 150),
      (1050, 90),
      (1350, 150),
      (1650, 90),
      (1950, 150)]

sr = 12.5
tl = list(tuple((str(timedelta(seconds=j/sr)) for j in i)) for i in il)

for t in tl:
    print(t)
```

prints:

```
('0:00:12', '0:00:12')
('0:00:36', '0:00:07.200000')
('0:01:00', '0:00:12')
('0:01:24', '0:00:07.200000')
('0:01:48', '0:00:12')
('0:02:12', '0:00:07.200000')
('0:02:36', '0:00:12')
```

[Edit: remove comment on output data mismatch.]

`time` doesn't appear to support string formatting to specify which fields to display or the number of fractional digits.  Use `re.match()` to strip off what you don't want, or convert seconds to int and back to string to get a fixed `dd.ddd` format.

Comment: actually when I wrote dummy data I mean actually dummy, I just typed random values to give the general idea about input organization (list of 2-tuples), and desired output (m:ss.sss and s:sss). Besides, I actually need the start time with minutes:seconds (without hours), and duration only in seconds (without hours and without minutes).

Comment: `time` always gives you the whole thing, so use string operations (slicing or re.match) to get rid of the parts you don't want.  That's the easy part, compared to the modulo arithmetic.